# Difference between numpy.linalg.solve and numpy.linalg.lu_solve

Tags: python, numpy

To solve a linear matrix equation one can use `numpy.linalg.solve`
which implements LAPACK routine [*gesv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html#ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512).

According to the documentation

```
DGESV computes the solution to a real system of linear equations
    A * X = B,
 where A is an N-by-N matrix and X and B are N-by-NRHS matrices.

 The LU decomposition with partial pivoting and row interchanges is
 used to factor A as
    A = P * L * U,
 where P is a permutation matrix, L is unit lower triangular, and U is
 upper triangular.  The factored form of A is then used to solve the
 system of equations A * X = B.
```

However, we can also use `scipy.linalg.lu_factor()` and `scipy.linalg.lu_solve()`
in order to solve our problem, where `lu_factor()` is

```
Compute pivoted LU decomposition of a matrix.

The decomposition is:

A = P L U

where P is a permutation matrix, 
L lower triangular with unit diagonal elements, 
and U upper triangular.
```

So apparently the two methods seem to be redundant. Is there any sense for this redundancy? Seems confusing to me..

Comment: How is this redundant? Not every LU-decomposition goes immediately into a solver. Similarly, if you're working with LU matrices then you have a solver you can use with your current matrix forms.

Comment: why would you want to have a LU-decomposition if not for solving am equation system?

Comment: Well you can get other information from an LU-decomposition---determinant, rank, etc. But I've seen it mostly used in the other direction---creating a LU matrix and then solving a system with it.

Comment: For these information `numpy.linalg` offers the appropriate functions.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed you are right: **chaining scipy's `scipy.linalg.lu_factor()` and `scipy.linalg.lu_solve()` is perfectly equivalent to numpy's `numpy.linalg.solve()`.** Nevertheless, **having access to the LU decomposition is a great advantage in practical situations.**

First, let's proove the equivalence. [`numpy.linalg.solve()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) states that:

> The solutions are computed using LAPACK routine _gesv

Indeed, the [github repository of numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/linalg) contains a lite version of LAPACK.
Then, let's take a look at the source of [`dgesv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d72/dgesv_8f_source.html) of LAPACK. The LU factorization of the matrix is computed and used to solve the linear system. Indeed, the source code of the function is very clear: appart for input checking, it boils down to calling `dgetrf` (LU factorization) and `dgetrs`. Finally, [`scipy.linalg.lu_factor()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/linalg/decomp_lu.py#L17) and [`scipy.linalg.lu_solve()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/linalg/decomp_lu.py#L75-L125) respectively wraps `dgetrf` and `dgetrs`, featuring lines like `getrf, = get_lapack_funcs(('getrf',), (a1,))` and `getrs, = get_lapack_funcs(('getrs',), (lu, b1))`.

As noticed by  @Alexander Reynolds , the LU decomposition can be useful to compute the determinant and the rank of the matrix. Indeed, regarding the determinant, **`numpy.det` call the LU factorization _getrf !** See the [source of numpy.linalg](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1095). Nevertheless, numpy compute the rank of matrices using the SVD decomposition.

But computing the rank using LU is not the only reason for exposing interfaces to `dgetrf` and `dgetrs`. There are indeed common situations where caling `dgetrf` once, keeping the LU factorization in memory and calling `dgetrs` many times is a decisive advantage. Look at **[iterative refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_refinement)** for instance. It must be noticed that **computing the LU factorization takes much more time (N^3) than solving a linear system using the factorization (N^2).**

Let's take a look at the **[Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to solve a system of coupled non-linear equation** F(x)=0 where F: R^N->R^N. Performing a Newton-Raphson iteration requires solving a linear system where the matrix is the Jacobian matrix J:

[image]

where x_{i+1} is the unknown. The Jacobian J(x_i) is often expensive to compute, not to mension the fact that the system must be solved. As a result, **quasi Newton methods** are often considered, where approximations of the Jacobian are built. A straightforward idea is not to update the Jacobian matrix every iteration and keep iterating as long as a norm of the residu decreases. **In such a process, `dgetrf` is called from time to time, while `dgetrs` is called once for every iteration.** See [there](https://dianafea.com/manuals/d943/Analys/node386.html) for a scheme. Let's look at an exemple : let's try to solve x^2=1 starting at x_0=2. For 4 iterations of the Newton method, we get f(x_4)=9.2e-8 and f(x_5)<1e-13. But if the Jacobian is updated once every ten iterations, only two evaluations of the Jacobian are required to get f(x_12)=5.7e-11 and f(x_13)=2.2e-14.

[image] [image]

There are even more efficient strategies which consist in **updating the LU decomposition once every iteration without factoring any matrix.** See ["Direct Secant Updates of Matrix Factorizations"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-38-158/S0025-5718-1982-0645663-8/S0025-5718-1982-0645663-8.pdf) of Denis and Marwil and ["EXPERIMENTS WITH QUASI-NEWTON METHODS IN SOLVING STIFF ODE SYSTEMS"](https://users.wpi.edu/~walker/Papers/qn_methods_for_stiff_ODEs,SISSC_6,1985,297-313.pdf) by Brown et. al.

As a result, in [non-linear finite element analysis](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Nonlinear_finite_elements), the assembly of the tangent stiffness is not always evaluated every Newton iteration ([option of Code_Aster in paragraph 3.10.2
MATRICE](http://www.code-aster.org/doc/v11/en/man_u/u4/u4.51.03.pdf)  or [diana](https://dianafea.com/manuals/d943/Analys/node386.html) or [here](http://www.nidaeurope.com/free-guides/38-numerical-methods-for-nonlinear-analysis) or [there](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/ans_thry/thy_tool10.html).

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of `solve` is O(n³), while that of `lu_solve` is O(n²). But that of `lu_factor` is O(n³). So, when you have many systems `Ax=b` with the same `A` but different `b`s, it is more efficient to `lu_factor` once and `lu_solve` than to use `solve`.